# When i use map api key location cannot change, show this issue in log:E/FrameEvents(32559): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps-api-3

```
D/DecorView[](16142): getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /pick-map?page=/&route=true
D/MapsInitializer(16142): preferredRenderer: null
D/zzca    (16142): preferredRenderer: null
I/zzca    (16142): Making Creator dynamically
I/DynamiteModule(16142): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203115000
I/DynamiteModule(16142): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203115000
V/DynamiteModule(16142): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/System  (16142): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
I/Google Maps Android API(16142): Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API(16142): Google Play services package version: 222615037
I/Google Maps Android API(16142): Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000
D/MapsInitializer(16142): loadedRenderer: LEGACY
D/zzca    (16142): preferredRenderer: null
I/Google Maps Android API(16142): Google Play services package version: 222615037
I/Google Maps Android API(16142): Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000
E/libc    (16142): Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
E/libc    (16142): Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.knock.type"
I/DpmTcmClient(16142): RegisterTcmMonitor from: $Proxy1
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/ba      (16142): Successfully registered with Phenotype.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/flutter (16142): ====> API Call: /api/v1/config/geocode-api?lat=22.3749745&lng=91.8063924
I/flutter (16142): Header: {Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, zoneId: null, X-localization: en, Authorization: Bearer null}
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/Counters(16142): exceeded sample count in FrameTime
E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/Counters(16142): exceeded sample count in FrameTime
```

Answer (score 0):

This same issue will happen when I implement Google maps

E/FrameEvents(16142): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).